# A cheap, large graphics tablet with a low footprint-to-input ratio

Tags: graphics-tablet

I'd like to buy a graphics tablet (also known as a drawing tablet, graphics pad, etc. - see [here](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/aboutgraphics/a/graphicstablets.htm) for some more information). I'm interested in using it for input for CAD programs, some of which use freehand sketching for input.

My criteria (from most to least important):

- A price under $150
- A low footprint-to-input ratio (for example, a 10-inch diagonal input space on a 15-inch diagonal tablet would be quite wasteful)
- A diagonal of roughly 6"-9"
- Wireless connection (e.g. Bluetooth capability).
- A pen with an eraser
- A pressure sensitivity of around 1024
- An overlay for tracing
- Compatibility with Windows 7

Things I don't need or want:

- An extra mouse, cordless or not, for the tablet
- A screen (working with an iPad is not what I'd like)
- USB connection (although this might be nice, as backup)
- The same aspect ratio as the computer it will be used with (software can take care of this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I researched digitizers Wacom was the clear solution.  I think they have a patent on their unpowered pen that gives them industry dominance.

You should get a Wacom Intuos Pen & Touch Tablet.  To stay in your budget you would have to go with the Small, model #CTH480, which runs ~$80 and provides a 6.0"x3.7" active area on an 8.25"x6.9" tablet.  Next step up is the Medium, model #CTH680, which runs ~$180 and provides an 8.5"x5.3" active area on a 10.75"x8.75" tablet.

Both sizes come with a pen with eraser and 1024 levels of pressure sensitivity.

Wireless connection for either requires an extra $40 accessory kit (model #ACK40401).

If you're tracing you probably do need to pony up for the Medium size.  But I do graphic design with the Small and even though it sounds like a tiny working area the resolution is so high that I don't have any trouble working on an HD monitor.